# Flutter not going through conditional statements correctly as intended

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code where  the conditional statement are not being followed as intended.

Here is the code:

```
onPressed: () async {
  if ((_formKey.currentState != null && _formKey.currentState!.validate()) ||
      (_formKey1.currentState != null && _formKey1.currentState!.validate())) {
    
    String apiResponse = await loginAPI(email, password);
    print("api response is: $apiResponse");

    if (apiResponse == 'false') {
      setState(() {
        isError = true;
        isErroremail = false;
        print("isError variable is set to true");
      });
    } else if (apiResponse == 'username false') {
      setState(() {
        isErroremail = true;
        isError = false;
        print("isErroremail variable is set to true");
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isError = false;
        isErroremail = false;
        print("isError and isErroremail variables are reset.");
      });
    }

    if (!isError && !isErroremail) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text("processing Data")),
      );
    }
  }
  print("button has been pressed");
},
```

Although the api response is `flutter: api response is: "username false"`

it does not go through the `else if (apiResponse == 'username false')` statement.

This can be verified by looking at the print statements:

```
flutter: api response is: "username false"
flutter: isError and isErroremail variables are reset.
flutter: button has been pressed
```

Comment: Might be the formatting, but are you sure the string does not also contain the quotes? So that the api response actually is: `"username false"` with the quotes and thus it reaches the else part. Because if that is the raw output below, it sure looks like it.

Comment: I will add this as an answer. Feel free to accept this or remove your question if you feel like it doesn't add any value anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`apiResponse` actually contains the quotes (") in the string (i.e. the content is `"username false"`). This is the reason why none of the conditions are met.